# load mysql dump in database using mysql C API

Tags: mysql, c, database, api

I want to manage a database in C language. So I am using C API for mysql.
I am unable to find a function in C API for loading the a `.sql` file directly to mysql.
I have gone through [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-functions.html) but didn't find it.

I also tried using `SOURCE file.sql` by giving it as a query but I am getting a weird error

> source error.You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SOURCE /home/iota/Academics/4-2/NP/a/a4/cars.sql' at line 1

Related code is below:

```
void connectdb(){

    con = mysql_init(NULL);

    if (mysql_real_connect(con, "localhost", "root", "psswd", NULL, 0, NULL, 0) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "qqddd%s\n", mysql_error(con));
        mysql_close(con);
        exit(1);
    }

    mysql_query(con, "drop database if exists testdb");
    mysql_query(con, "create database testdb");


    if(mysql_query(con, "use testdb")){
        fprintf(stderr, "qq%s\n", mysql_error(con));
        mysql_close(con);
        exit(1);                
    }


    if(mysql_query(con, "SOURCE /home/iota/Academics/4-2/NP/a/a4/cars.sql")){ /*error here*/
        fprintf(stderr, "source error.%s\n", mysql_error(con));
        mysql_close(con);
        exit(1);        
    }


}
```

Could you please suggest any way to do this ?
Thank you.

Comment: [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage But what if I want to load all of the data in ```.sql``` file at once ?

Comment: *The LOAD DATA INFILE statement reads rows from a text file into a table at a very high speed.* — isn't that what you wanted to do?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage It worked ! thanks. But could you please point mistakes/solutions to above question apart from this ? I mean above code should also work right ?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is no `SOURCE` command in the MySQL API. It only exists in the `mysql` command line application as a convenient way of sourcing input from a file.

Comment: But why is that query related to source not working ? Are some types of query not allowed in mysql C API ?

Comment: The [mysql command line tool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-commands.html) and the [MySQL command set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/dynindex-statement.html) are two different things. One contains a `source` command. The other doesn't. If you want to send your server a query that causes it to read in a .sql file, use `LOAD DATA INFILE`. The `source` command only works in the command line tool.